# Google Chrome GPU Driver Issues on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, chrome, gpu

I am having some problems starting Google Chrome on Ubuntu 18.04, and it seems to have something to do with my GPU driver--however, I do not know for sure.

I tried `google-chrome` from the command line, and it gave me the following;

```
theo@nitrates:~$ google-chrome
[29617:29617:1003/171104.939355:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(379)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[29617:29617:1003/171105.478055:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171105.490579:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171105.531946:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171105.569271:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171105.585473:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171105.595687:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171105.665439:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171105.678878:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171105.869643:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171105.908701:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171106.012723:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171106.014180:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171106.030990:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171106.041881:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
[29617:29617:1003/171106.062463:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
```

Some important things to note:

1. There seems to be (some) unpredictability in this issue. Several times I have simply clicked on chrome or started it from the command line, and it starts up just fine. It is almost as if it goes through phases of working and *not* working.
2. There seems to be a slightly higher rate of success when attempting to start it **right** after the computer has restarted / woken up from being shut down.
3. This is a MacBook Pro from 2010 (15 inch retina), with the NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M and the "Intel HD Graphics with 256 MB of DDR3 SDRAM" as per [this site](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.4-aluminum-15-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html).

EDIT:

Tried `google-chrome --use-gl=osmesa --disable-gl-drawing-for-tests` as recommended in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473116/288705), and got the following error:

```
[1416:1416:1003/175305.577073:ERROR:gl_implementation.cc(291)] Failed to load /opt/google/chrome/libosmesa.so: /opt/google/chrome/libosmesa.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[1416:1416:1003/175305.579670:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(236)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[1361:1379:1003/175305.581582:ERROR:service_manager_context.cc(270)] Attempting to run unsupported native service: /opt/google/chrome/content_gpu.service
[1361:1361:1003/175306.061430:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
```

Comment: Hello @Theodore Weld. Did you see this issue in previous versions of google chrome? or just after and upgrade to a newer version?

Comment: @Goro I do not know if this has something to do with an update necessarily. Currently I am on 69.0.3497.92 and have not ever updated it myself since installation.

Comment: Yeah so it seems that that file does not exist, I will update my answer with the error as that would be a nicer way to see it.

Comment: @Goro I did check this—doesn’t seem to be there.

Comment: There are many different releases of `libgles2-mesa` for Ubuntu 18.04 try the closest to your system.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you do the following:

1) Check whether you have "libgles2-mesa" installed?  If not, then [install it](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/libgles2-mesa).

2) Try disabling GPU-accelerated compositing under the flag "--use-gl=osmesa" using the command:

```
google-chrome --use-gl=osmesa --disable-gl-drawing-for-tests
```

Answer (score 0):

Install NVidia drivers:
Run the commands:

1. `ubuntu-drivers devices`
2. `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-(your device)`
   -or-
   `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
3. `reboot`

Comment: Is `ubuntu-drivers devices` a command to be typed?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.